# The base class or interface 'System.MarshalByRefObject' in assembly could not be resolved

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, archive, 7zip

I am creating a Windows 8 app for compression/extraction archive files. I want to use 7-zip library so I rushed to [SevenZipSharp](https://sevenzipsharp.codeplex.com). Then created a new project passed reference of managed SevenZipSharp.dll and also added unmanaged 7z.dll (x86 version) in project (build action set to content & copy to output directory set to Copy if newer). When I tried to run the project as I am getting this error.

> The base class or interface 'System.MarshalByRefObject' in assembly
>   'mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' referenced by type
>   'SevenZip.SevenZipBase' could not be resolved

What's the meaning of it? Do I need to re-compile SevenZipSharp.dll to work within WinRT?

My first choice is of course SevenZipSharp otherwise I would go for [SharpCompress](https://github.com/adamhathcock/sharpcompress)

Comment: It looks like [`MarshalByRefObject` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.marshalbyrefobject.aspx) is not included in _Portable Class Library_ or _.NET for Windows Store apps_. Your assembly has a class `SevenZipBase` that derives from it.

Comment: So any solution for it? There could be, otherwise why [this](http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/en-us/app/8-zip/0ca9b05e-9acb-4b91-a3f2-8d2c7545b0fe) app exist?